# VbsJson is returning Object Required due to a parsing error

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I am new to JSON, and I am attempting to read a string in JSON format returned from a data source.  I am using classic ASP, and I am getting the following error from the class code for VbsJson.

Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01a8'

Object required

/MyTestPage.asp, line 83

Below in the code I comment where the error is occuring.  My desire is for the code to parse and provide the key/value pair of data to sort through.

Here is the JSON string

```
[
  {
    "branchNumber": null,
    "createdOn": "2017-02-03T22:44:22.656062",
    "employeeId": "00",
    "id": "0000000-000F-DB00-999D",
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2017-02-04T17:26:37.137217",
    "name": {
      "firstName": "MyFirstName",
      "lastName": "MyLastName",
      "middleNamesOrInitial": null,
      "preferredFirstName": null,
      "prefix": null,
      "suffix": null
    },
    "userName": "MyEMail@MyCorp.com"
  },
  {
    "branchNumber": null,
    "createdOn": "2017-02-03T22:44:22.656062",
    "employeeId": "01",
    "id": "0000000-000F-DB00-999F",
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2017-02-04T17:26:37.137217",
    "name": {
      "firstName": "MyFirstName",
      "lastName": "MyLastName",
      "middleNamesOrInitial": null,
      "preferredFirstName": null,
      "prefix": null,
      "suffix": null
    },
    "userName": "MyEMail2@MyCorp.com"
  }
]
```

Here is my code calling VbsJson:

```
Dim simonResponseArray
Dim jsonClsUser, jsonParsedUser

Dim fso, json
Set json = New VbsJson
Set fso = server.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
simonXmlResponse = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\users_small.json").ReadAll

Set jsonClsUser = New VbsJson
Set jsonParsedUser = jsonClsUser.Decode(simonXmlResponse) 'This is where the error occurs
```

Also, below is the class code for VbsJson:

```
Class VbsJson
'Author: Demon
'Date: 2012/5/3
'Website: http://demon.tw
Private Whitespace, NumberRegex, StringChunk
Private b, f, r, n, t

Private Sub Class_Initialize
    Whitespace = " " & vbTab & vbCr & vbLf
    b = ChrW(8)
    f = vbFormFeed
    r = vbCr
    n = vbLf
    t = vbTab

    Set NumberRegex = New RegExp
    NumberRegex.Pattern = "(-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*))(\.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d+)?"
    NumberRegex.Global = False
    NumberRegex.MultiLine = True
    NumberRegex.IgnoreCase = True

    Set StringChunk = New RegExp
    StringChunk.Pattern = "([\s\S]*?)([""\\\x00-\x1f])"
    StringChunk.Global = False
    StringChunk.MultiLine = True
    StringChunk.IgnoreCase = True
End Sub

'Return a JSON string representation of a VBScript data structure
'Supports the following objects and types
'+-------------------+---------------+
'| VBScript          | JSON          |
'+===================+===============+
'| Dictionary        | object        |
'+-------------------+---------------+
'| Array             | array         |
'+-------------------+---------------+
'| String            | string        |
'+-------------------+---------------+
'| Number            | number        |
'+-------------------+---------------+
'| True              | true          |
'+-------------------+---------------+
'| False             | false         |
'+-------------------+---------------+
'| Null              | null          |
'+-------------------+---------------+
Public Function Encode(ByRef obj)
    Dim buf, i, c, g
    Set buf = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Select Case VarType(obj)
        Case vbNull
            buf.Add buf.Count, "null"
        Case vbBoolean
            If obj Then
                buf.Add buf.Count, "true"
            Else
                buf.Add buf.Count, "false"
            End If
        Case vbInteger, vbLong, vbSingle, vbDouble
            buf.Add buf.Count, obj
        Case vbString
            buf.Add buf.Count, """"
            For i = 1 To Len(obj)
                c = Mid(obj, i, 1)
                Select Case c
                    Case """" buf.Add buf.Count, "\"""
                    Case "\"  buf.Add buf.Count, "\\"
                    Case "/"  buf.Add buf.Count, "/"
                    Case b    buf.Add buf.Count, "\b"
                    Case f    buf.Add buf.Count, "\f"
                    Case r    buf.Add buf.Count, "\r"
                    Case n    buf.Add buf.Count, "\n"
                    Case t    buf.Add buf.Count, "\t"
                    Case Else
                        If AscW(c) >= 0 And AscW(c) <= 31 Then
                            c = Right("0" & Hex(AscW(c)), 2)
                            buf.Add buf.Count, "\u00" & c
                        Else
                            buf.Add buf.Count, c
                        End If
                End Select
            Next
            buf.Add buf.Count, """"
        Case vbArray + vbVariant
            g = True
            buf.Add buf.Count, "["
            For Each i In obj
                If g Then g = False Else buf.Add buf.Count, ","
                buf.Add buf.Count, Encode(i)
            Next
            buf.Add buf.Count, "]"
        Case vbObject
            If TypeName(obj) = "Dictionary" Then
                g = True
                buf.Add buf.Count, "{"
                For Each i In obj
                    If g Then g = False Else buf.Add buf.Count, ","
                    buf.Add buf.Count, """" & i & """" & ":" & Encode(obj(i))
                Next
                buf.Add buf.Count, "}"
            Else
                Err.Raise 8732,,"None dictionary object"
            End If
        Case Else
            buf.Add buf.Count, """" & CStr(obj) & """"
    End Select
    Encode = Join(buf.Items, "")
End Function

'Return the VBScript representation of ``str(``
'Performs the following translations in decoding
'+---------------+-------------------+
'| JSON          | VBScript          |
'+===============+===================+
'| object        | Dictionary        |
'+---------------+-------------------+
'| array         | Array             |
'+---------------+-------------------+
'| string        | String            |
'+---------------+-------------------+
'| number        | Double            |
'+---------------+-------------------+
'| true          | True              |
'+---------------+-------------------+
'| false         | False             |
'+---------------+-------------------+
'| null          | Null              |
'+---------------+-------------------+
Public Function Decode(ByRef str)
    Dim idx
    str=Replace(str,"[]","[""""]")
    str=Replace(str,"{}","[""""]")

    idx = SkipWhitespace(str, 1)
    If Mid(str, idx, 1) = "{" Then
        Set Decode = ScanOnce(str, 1)
    Else
        Decode = ScanOnce(str, 1)
    End If
End Function

Private Function ScanOnce(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
    Dim c, ms

    idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
    c = Mid(str, idx, 1)

    If c = "{" Then
        idx = idx + 1
        Set ScanOnce = ParseObject(str, idx)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf c = "[" Then
        idx = idx + 1
        ScanOnce = ParseArray(str, idx)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf c = """" Then
        idx = idx + 1
        ScanOnce = ParseString(str, idx)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf c = "n" And StrComp("null", Mid(str, idx, 4)) = 0 Then
        idx = idx + 4
        ScanOnce = Null
        Exit Function
    ElseIf c = "t" And StrComp("true", Mid(str, idx, 4)) = 0 Then
        idx = idx + 4
        ScanOnce = True
        Exit Function
    ElseIf c = "f" And StrComp("false", Mid(str, idx, 5)) = 0 Then
        idx = idx + 5
        ScanOnce = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set ms = NumberRegex.Execute(Mid(str, idx))
    If ms.Count = 1 Then
        idx = idx + ms(0).Length
        ScanOnce = CDbl(ms(0))
        Exit Function
    End If

    Err.Raise 8732,,"No JSON object could be ScanOnced"
End Function

Private Function ParseObject(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
    Dim c, key, value
    Set ParseObject = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
    c = Mid(str, idx, 1)

    If c = "}" Then
        Exit Function
    ElseIf c <> """" Then
        Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting property name"
    End If

    idx = idx + 1

    Do
        key = ParseString(str, idx)

        idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
        If Mid(str, idx, 1) <> ":" Then
            Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting : delimiter"
        End If

        idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx + 1)
        If Mid(str, idx, 1) = "{" Then
            Set value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
        Else
            value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
        End If
        ParseObject.Add key, value

        idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
        c = Mid(str, idx, 1)
        If c = "}" Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf c <> "," Then
            Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting , delimiter"
        End If

        idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx + 1)
        c = Mid(str, idx, 1)
        If c <> """" Then
            Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting property name"
        End If

        idx = idx + 1
    Loop

    idx = idx + 1
End Function

Private Function ParseArray(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
    Dim c, values, value
    Set values = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
    c = Mid(str, idx, 1)

    If c = "]" Then
        ParseArray = values.Items
        Exit Function
    End If

    Do
        idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
        If Mid(str, idx, 1) = "{" Then
            Set value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
        Else
            value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
        End If
        values.Add values.Count, value

        idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
        c = Mid(str, idx, 1)
        If c = "]" Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf c <> "," Then
            Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting , delimiter"
        End If

        idx = idx + 1
    Loop

    idx = idx + 1
    ParseArray = values.Items
End Function

Private Function ParseString(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
    Dim chunks, content, terminator, ms, esc, char
    Set chunks = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Do
        Set ms = StringChunk.Execute(Mid(str, idx))
        If ms.Count = 0 Then
            Err.Raise 8732,,"Unterminated string starting"
        End If

        content = ms(0).Submatches(0)
        terminator = ms(0).Submatches(1)
        If Len(content) > 0 Then
            chunks.Add chunks.Count, content
        End If

        idx = idx + ms(0).Length

        If terminator = """" Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf terminator <> "\" Then
            Err.Raise 8732,,"Invalid control character"
        End If

        esc = Mid(str, idx, 1)

        If esc <> "u" Then
            Select Case esc
                Case """" char = """"
                Case "\"  char = "\"
                Case "/"  char = "/"
                Case "b"  char = b
                Case "f"  char = f
                Case "n"  char = n
                Case "r"  char = r
                Case "t"  char = t
                Case Else Err.Raise 8732,,"Invalid escape"
            End Select
            idx = idx + 1
        Else
            char = ChrW("&H" & Mid(str, idx + 1, 4))
            idx = idx + 5
        End If

        chunks.Add chunks.Count, char
    Loop

    ParseString = Join(chunks.Items, "")
End Function

Private Function SkipWhitespace(ByRef str, ByVal idx)
    Do While idx <= Len(str) And _
        InStr(Whitespace, Mid(str, idx, 1)) > 0
        idx = idx + 1
    Loop
    SkipWhitespace = idx
End Function

End Class
```

If there is anymore info someone needs, please let me know.  Consuming JSON from classic ASP has proven difficult for me.

Comment: Which line in MyTestPage.asp is line 83?

Comment: Why is this off-topic? OP has provided enough info

Comment: I will happily edit this question to be on-topic, so can someone tell me what I am leaving out that caused this question to be closed.

Comment: One cause for the "object required" error is to use Set for assignments of non-objects. Your json is an array of dictionaries, i.e. a non-object. Remove the Set, and your code will 'work' (tested). As to the question "why was my question closed?": Some people - most of them never having answered a VBScript questions - have problems to understand VBscript questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data is an **array** of objects/dictionaries. So your

```
Set jsonParsedUser = jsonClsUser.Decode(simonXmlResponse)
```

should be:

```
jsonParsedUser = jsonClsUser.Decode(simonXmlResponse)
```

(`Set` is used for assignment of objects; see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44(v=vs.84).aspx))